# Search for period N logistic map

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, chaos

The logistic map is a [period doubling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Period-doubling_bifurcation#:%7E:text=In%20dynamical%20systems%20theory%2C%20a,the%20period%20of%20the%20original.) bifurcation system.

Are there known dynamical maps, which oscillate between $N$ points where $N$ is a prime number, like 2, 3, or 5, or 7... , where each successive bifurcation makes the system oscillate between $N^i$  ( $Ii$ is a positive integer) values $x_1,x_2, ... x_N$?

And if so, then does there exist a value $N$ such that by changing the system parameters (such as the parameter $r$ for the original logistic map) it is possible to reach any given real values $x_1, x_2,...x_N$? ( rational or otherwise). Does it make a difference if we restrict ourselves in only rationals? Does it make any difference if we restrict ourselves such that $x_1, x_2...$ are integers only? You know what, while we are at it, does it make any difference if we hold them within a certain interval large enough to fit $N$ integers?

The original logistic map, at the first bifurcation does have a quadratic term to calculate the two values the system will oscillate in between. But the quadratic term means that there will be values that $x_1$ and $x_2$ cannot reach using any real value of $r$.

But does that hold true for other primes $N$ and the maps that oscillate between values given by such $N$ ?

Thank you.